# Passing generic enums in Warp query

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I have an enum that is serde serializable in Rust.The enum has generics involved. Is there a way to get warp to accept this enum as a part of a warp query.

```
enum A<T> {
 a(T),
}
```

such that we can have ,

```
let route = warp::get()
            .and(warp::path(“/“)
            .and(warp::query::A<T>)
            ….
```

I have tried a lot of ways but warp seems to throw a compilation error.

Comment: You can do for example do this with `.and(warp::path::param::<A<()>>())`. But seeing that your syntax is quite broken, I suggest you invest some time into learning more Rust before you try using web server libraries. Those do usually make quite heavy use of Rust's features, i.e. require solid knowledge about types and traits and what all of those `::<>` do.

Comment: How would warp decide what type `T` should be?